# What's in the newsletter, exactly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The newsletter ad has some problems; you can't read what it's about:

[image]

unless you select the text:

[image]

Only Worldbuilding seems to have this problem; I checked a couple of other sites (e.g. [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)) where it looks normal:

[image]

<sub>(tested in the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS High Sierra)</sub>

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome 68.0 on Windows. Looks like WorldBuilding has the color set to white in #sidebar #newsletter-ad, whereas the color property is missing from Puzzling.

Comment: Also reproduced on the latest Firefox on Windows as well as the mobile 'desktop site'

Comment: Same thing on Firefox ESR 52.9 on Linux. It used to have a dark green background; looks like that got lost somewhere in a design "upgrade"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with the [new design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/worldbuildings-updated-site-theme-is-live-for-everyone?cb=1):

[image]