# What's wrong with printing in Worldbuilding

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It seems that there is something wrong with Worldbuilding's CSS styles for print media or other configurations that prevents pages to be printed (either on a paper or to a PDF) correctly.

When printing the main text is terribly narrowed:

[image]

The above is tested under five different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge and IE) and is as best as it can be -- under Chrome. Under other browser printed strip is even more narrowed, i.e.:

- under Firefox and Opera first line of above text consists of "*In my world there's*" only,
- under Edge it is only "*In my world*" and "*there's a*" is in the next line.

Printing is out of question with such narrow text. Edge claims that a print of [the question in topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117221/how-to-kidnap-a-person-so-the-world-wouldnt-object-or-ask-questions) would require 50 (!) pages.

Edge, as the only browser of all five tested, has an option called *Clutter-free printing*. Enabling it causes page to be printed quite normally (no text narrowing, quite normal margins, print as close to regular Word document as it can be).

But something (probably again CSS/HTML) causes Edge to print question only, even though "*All pages*" is selected and even tough with *Clutter-free printing* turned off causes Edge to print whole page (question + all answers).

Comment: Is this specific to Worldbuilding?

Comment: Same here, only even worse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXbVy.png

Comment: I think this should go on [Worldbuilding's updated site theme is live for everyone!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6744/29) instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! We're aware of this and working on a solution. I'm not sure how soon we'll be able to get it fixed. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Catija Then I think someone out of moderators or administrators should write an short notice / answer here and we can close the topic (waiting for the solution). Thx!

Comment: Everytime I see "printing"... it always reminds me of [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) that is often mentioned on [the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877/241919) :)

Comment: It's worth noting that "close" means something different on SE. This question wouldn't be closed by our definition. When posts have accepted answers (which is what I'm guessing you're talking about), that means that the OP is happy with the solution they have but I have no solution as this bug being reported isn't fixed yet, which would be the solution by our definition.

Comment: Sure thing! :> By "close" I meant here to have an answer provided so other people stopping by this question wouldn't have to dig for an answer through comments.

Comment: @AndrewT. I wasn't aware of stackprint.com and I find it very, very useful. I'd suggest adding an information to possible answer to this question that such service exists and can be used when fixes for print CSS to this site are rolled out (and not only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329187/235711